# VB.NET PowerShell Cmdlet Start-Transcript

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am writing a VB.NET PowerShell Cmdlet which needs to start, and later stop, the Transcript file (Start-Transcript). 
So how do I manage to run the command *Start-Transcript* from within the cmdlet? I have tried this:

```
Dim myRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
myRunSpace.Open()
Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Start-Transcript -Path $pwd\session.txt")
Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
myRunSpace.Close()
```

Produces the error "Start-transcript : this host does not support transription". Yet when I enter the command manually
no error is produced and transcription starts.

Answer (score 0):

The Start-Transcript method is host specific and implemented by the host. The reason for this, I'm guessing, is that it is not clear what input and output is available on different hosts and therefore not easy to create a generic implementation which works in all cases.

The PowerShell Console host supports the Start-Transcript function (which you see, since it works when you call it), but other hosts need to implement it before it is usable in that host. If you, for example, try to write Start-Transcript in the PowerShell ISE host you'll get an error like the following:

```
Start-Transcript : This host does not support transcription.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Transcript
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Start-Transcript], PSNotSupportedExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscript 
   Command
```

In order to get it to work using a custom host such as the one you're creating in VB you would have to find a way to implement support for transcription.

Comment: Actually all I am trying to do is to detect if it transcribing, as I need to edit the transcript file which is locked in such a case, and I can detect this if Start-Transcript throws an error. Also, apparently, the obscure $transcript variable seldom works.

Comment: Then your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170237/powershell-how-to-check-if-transcript-is-running

Comment: Perhaps not, since you actually want to edit the file as well. I don't know of a way to check whether transcript is currently being recorded or not. I don't know what $transcript is, a variable you're setting yourself? There are no changes of variables by calling Start-Transcript (do 'ls variable:' before and after to check) in PowerShell Console, as far as I can see. I'm guessing if such a variable would exist, this would also be host specific.

Comment: ` $externalHost = $host.gettype().getproperty("ExternalHost",
       [reflection.bindingflags]"NonPublic,Instance").getvalue($host, @())

 try {
     $externalHost.gettype().getproperty("IsTranscribing",
I found this PS code which looks promising, but converting to VB.Net is beyond me!  [reflection.bindingflags]"NonPublic,Instance").getvalue($externalHost, @())
 } catch {
             write-warning "This host does not support transcription."
         }`

Answer (score 0):

That is a limitation of the cmdlet. MSFT made it so Start-Transcript only works when invoked from powershell.exe console, it doesn't even work from their ISE. The workaround has been to use add-content / out-file / tee-object to create your own log file.

It's a lot more work, but can be done.  maybe these cmdlets can help.

http://www.powertheshell.com/transcript/

Comment: Can I rephrase my question then - is it possible to detect whether the session is transcribing or not? As I commented above the $transcript variable is supposed to give the path to the transcript file but seldom works, otherwise I could get the value of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed one of your earlier links and patched this VB.NET code from the *PowerShell* script there:

```
 Dim thisType As Object = MyBase.Host.GetType().GetProperty("ExternalHost",Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(MyBase.Host, New Object() {})
 Dim abc As Object = thisType.GetType().GetProperty("IsTranscribing", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(thisType, New Object() {})
 WriteObject(abc.ToString)
```

This returns correctly *True* or *False*. So can I do any more than this here, ie like *Stop-Transcript*? Apologies for the comment above, but this link is slow and the text became garbled.